# Paired t-test for N > 30

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have 2 samples, and I want to test difference in means to see if they are related so I think I need to do a paired t-test.  There are over 60 observations in each pair.  Can one use paired t-test for N over 30?

Comment: "*I want to test difference in means to see if they are related*" -- a paired t-test doesn't test to see if the means are 'related'. It tests if they're different. But yes, if the assumptions hold, it works for any number of pairs ... as long as there's more than one pair.

Comment: **Note:** I suspect the OP's native language is not English.

Comment: @gung I also suspect so, since it's the case for many posters and the source of much ambiguity in questions, but that makes the issue even more necessary to point out -  the language issue raises the possibility that they have mistakenly chosen a test for differences between means when they actually want a test of relatedness; an OP mentioning both leaves either mistake as a possibility. It's worth raising the distinction in order that the OP clarify what it is that they want.

Comment: @user27775, in light of Glen_b's comments, it would help if you could clarify your situation. I would also take a look at John's answer, & see if your situation is like the cases he's describing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  in fact, the larger the $N$ the better.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the way you've written your question you cannot use a paired t-test.  You said, "there are over 60 observations in each pair." That suggests 60 observations in each group. You probably need an independent samples t-test.  But it's hard to tell.

You use a paired samples t-test if you have matched pairs of observations in some way.  One way that's done is by taking two measures of each subject.  Those measures are paired by being within subjects.  Another way might be married couples where you're taking a measure between sexes but it's husband and wife. The samples will be paired by couple. You haven't described a scenario like that so it's likely you need an independent samples t-test.

As for the N in each group, the larger the better. And, the more similar the better.

Comment: When I said they're related I should have said they meet the standard of matched pairs. In the textbook I have the paired T Test is also described as a small sample test, this is my concern that the test is not valid for N over 30.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It is very much valid to use the paired $t$-test as long as you have 1) data that can be paired and therefore a difference can be calculated 2) differences which are normally distributed 3) if your number of pairs is larger than 30, the $t$-distribution will approach the $z$-distribution, so either one is acceptable, but typically for large number of pairs one resorts to the $z$-distribution.  In this case the normality requirement is relaxed based on the Central Limit Theorem.